# Visual Studio Solution icons and file versions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

This isn't an important question, but something that has been bothering me for awhile and my google-fu wasn't able to find an answer.

I know that Visual Studio 2013 is version 12 and Visual Studio 2012 is version 11.

Why did Microsoft make the icon for VS2013 solutions have 12 in it (their version number).  And VS2012 solutions have 11 in it (again the version number)?  VS2010 solutions correctly has 10 in the icon, even though the file format says its version 11.

Now this might just be on my machine(s) because I have multiple versions of VS installed (and editions), but it is just something that makes my head itch.

Answer (score 0):

```
The numbers correspond to the internal version numbers of various editions of Visual Studio


Visual Studio 6.0 (1998)
Visual Studio .NET (2002) = version 7
Visual Studio .NET 2003 = version 7.1
Visual Studio 2005 = version 8
Visual Studio 2008 = version 9
Visual Studio 2010 = version 10
Visual Studio 2012 = version 11
Visual Studio 2013 = version 12
Visual Studio 2015 = version 14

The number on the icon indicates the version that the project or solution is compatible with.
```

this info is taken from :
[Wikipedia_VS_Version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Version_history)

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my original question.  I was mainly just wondering why they didn't rejigger the version numbers to match the year, since they've started referring to the products by the year name.

Comment: I think this [INFO: Visual Studio version numbers](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2011/MZ2011011.aspx) can support your question.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is old, it is a general question on its own.

I was wandering to get a meaningful answer (because I wondered too) and get here only to find an incomplete one. Not satisfied and tried an editing trick on ".sln" file to get the answer.

At first, it is easy to find version numbering on Microsoft's own pages or wikipedia etc. Now the thing is having that number on "the sln file icon". That would be the answer to this question if I had asked it.

Open the sln file with a text editor as its content is mere text. Now the "format version" part on the first line is relevant to the content of the file, so not relevant to answer. The version number on the second line for VS version "# Visual Studio 15" is the thing what gives the file its icon. Changing the number and saving the file is immediate to change the number on the icon. Currently, 10,11,14 and 15 versions are supported it seems. By the way, if you have a line of "VisualStudioVersion", you need to delete it before saving to see the effect.

But be careful: even though you may change the icon, if the content format is not right, VS will complain about the solution. Don't forget to revert the changes back. And also this part gives a clue that you can write your own solution file in a text editor.

As to "why bother!!" of the question, an answer would be to recognize a solution version by look before opening it in the VS. You may have an older version of the file which possibly has incompatibilities in the project files inside, thus you can decide to do some adjustments by hand before opening it in your installed VS version.

PS: I once thought the "10" in the icon is "IO" for "input/output" terminology and wondered what "15" might be as I read it to be "IS". Found this Q/A, not satisfied and tried to improve. If you like, don't forget to give up vote.